# Return values when using Delegate with sendAndLoad in a AS2 class file

Tags: actionscript, delegates, actionscript-2, onload

I have a Flash animation with AS2 code that calls sendAndLoad in a separate class file, and following guides online I've used a Delegate to handle the onLoad part, like this:

```
ActionScript Code in class:
function myFunction():String{
...
var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var saveresult_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
send_lv.dataString = rc4_hash;      send_lv.sendAndLoad("<my url>",saveresult_lv,"POST");
saveresult_lv.onLoad = Delegate.create(this, onLoad);
}

function onLoad (success:Boolean) {
if (success) {
}else{
}
}
```

I've got two issues:

1. Because I call myFunction() from my .fla file, how do I send the result of onLoad() back as the return value of myFunction()?
2. How do I refer to variables that were created inside myFunction from within onLoad?
3. In my fla file, I have code like this:

   myVar:String=myFunction();

If onLoad takes any time then I think that myFunction() is returning nothing, and myVar ends up undefined. How do I get the fla to wait for the onLoad in the class file to finish and then populate myVar with the result?

Many thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: `onLoad` will never be called immediately, but when the data is received (even if that takes 1ms). You will always have to wait and continue your application from the onLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Your class could be restructured to answer your questions.

Separate the constructor, load function and result operation. When load is ready, the class can dispatch an event. Your FLA can listen to this event.

```
// Class code should something like this: (my AS2 is a little rusty)
class Sender {
    private var classSavedData:String;
    // these three vars are needed to use EventDispatcher.
    public var addEventListener:Function;
    public var removeEventListener:Function;
    public var dispatchEvent:Function;


    // Make your class ready to send events
    public function Sender() {
        EventDispatcher.initialize(this);          
    }
    public function loadData(){
        classSavedData = "Something the FLA can pick up after loading";
        var send_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
        var saveresult_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
        send_lv.dataString = rc4_hash;      
        end_lv.sendAndLoad("<my url>",saveresult_lv,"POST");
        saveresult_lv.onLoad = Delegate.create(this, onLoad);   
    }
    private function onLoad():Void {
        dispatchEvent({target:this, type:"eventFired", loadAnswer: saveresult_lv , extraData:classSavedData});         
    }
}
```

... and code in FLA can look like this:

```
var myClassInstance:Sender = new Sender()
myClassInstance.addEventListener ("eventFired", Delegate.create (this, onDataLoaded))
myClassInstance.loadData()
function onDataLoaded(evt:Object){
    trace ("loaded loadvars "+evt.loadAnswer)
}
```